Apply general settings on multiple image buttons Android Studio
enter image description here
I wanna make multiple buttons organized in a horizontal linear layout, but every buttons have common fields such as android:layout_marginStart="10dp", android:background="@null", android:scaleType="centerInside". Is there an better way to do that in order to assign this fields to every single button and not copy and paste them?  Thank you
enter image description here
As I explain, im looking for a pattern for all the buttons with common field. Thank you!

Use a style: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/themes

Try not to post images of text and use markdown to format your posts.

Try adding those common features into res\values\styles (If you don't have one then create) and then apply the styles to all the required imageButton.
 <style name="ImageButtonStyle">
 ="10dp", android:background="@null", android:scaleType="centerInside"
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
        //and many more attributes as u like.
        <item name="android:textAlignment">viewStart</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/urbanist_medium</item>
    </style>

Then use it in xml like this.
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/txtDate"
    style="@style/ImageButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

